# Is there any way to use Windows 7 multitouch from Java?

Tags: java, windows-7, multi-touch

I'm aware of [MT4j](http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) and the [Windows 7 Multitouch Interop Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch), but neither of these seem to be what I'm looking for: the MT4j code is pretty terrible and not well-documented, and the Win7 library seems to be a .NET assembly (and thus not able to be used natively by Java). Is there anyway to be able to get WM_TOUCH messages in Java? Or is it possible to actually use the Win 7 interop library from within Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't. There's only a kind of workaround...

Touch2TUIO is a open source command line tool, that can native Windows 7 touch messages translate/forward to the TUIO Protocol (so you could use them in Java or any other language). Still in development, but on most hardware already usable (and its open source - so everyone is free to make changes/improvements to it). It's not exactly, what you're looking for, but maybe the only solution now...

Touch2TUIO: http://dm.tzi.de/research/hci/touch2tuio/

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by pretty horribly code and not well documented? I built a huge MT4J application and have used the API of the MT4J latest versions and have had no problem with it.

Perhaps you could suggest some improvements on the documentation and/or API of that library. From my own experience I can tell you it's a worth multitouch framework to try. 
In the Java world is the only one I know of by the way.

Comment: Hmm? But not with the mentioned Windows 7 Touchevents, or didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 2.2+ perfectly supports multitouch for win7